# How to deploy Gradle module that is dependent on a module in the same code base to AWS Lambda via SAM?

Tags: gradle, aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I am currently working on a monorepo of Lambda functions.
Currently there are 4 independent Gradle modules. One of the four modules contains all shared code, and the three other modules represent a Lambda function. Each of these three modules is dependent on the fourth shared module.

The subproject dependency import is achieved through:
`settings.gradle`

```
include ':commons'
project(":commons").projectDir = file("../../commons")
```

and `build.gradle`:

```
implementation project(":commons")
```

Building the dependent modules directly through Gradle works fine, the problem is when I try to build/deploy with AWS SAM.

After running `sam build --debug`, I get the following:

```
2021-01-03 18:50:45,589 | Telemetry endpoint configured to be https://aws-serverless-tools-telemetry.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/metrics
2021-01-03 18:50:45,716 | 'build' command is called
2021-01-03 18:50:45,720 | No Parameters detected in the template
2021-01-03 18:50:45,743 | 1 resources found in the template
2021-01-03 18:50:45,743 | Found Serverless function with name='DailyUpdateFunction' and CodeUri='.'
2021-01-03 18:50:45,744 | No Parameters detected in the template
2021-01-03 18:50:45,770 | Instantiating build definitions
2021-01-03 18:50:45,773 | Same function build definition found, adding function (Previous: BuildDefinition(java11, ., Zip, , a50fb9b9-79f6-48f1-a4dc-51818ab36e50, {}, []), Current: BuildDefinition(java11, ., Zip, , e9cb278a-418b-4322-b626-eaca6512385c, {}, []), Function: Function(name='DailyUpdateFunction', functionname='DailyUpdateFunction', runtime='java11', memory=512, timeout=20, handler='lechads.fantasybball.LambdaHandler::handleRequest', imageuri=None, packagetype='Zip', imageconfig=None, codeuri='.', environment={'Variables': {'ENV': 'PROD'}}, rolearn=None, layers=[], events={'NoonDailyUpdate': {'Type': 'Schedule', 'Properties': {'Schedule': 'cron(0, 17, *, *, ?, *)', 'Name': 'noon-daily-update', 'Enabled': True}}}, metadata=None, codesign_config_arn=None))
2021-01-03 18:50:45,774 | Building codeuri: . runtime: java11 metadata: {} functions: ['DailyUpdateFunction']
2021-01-03 18:50:45,774 | Building to following folder /Users/cschafer/Desktop/fantasy_bball_slack_integration/components/daily_update/.aws-sam/build/DailyUpdateFunction
2021-01-03 18:50:45,774 | Looking for a supported build workflow in following directories: ['/Users/cschafer/Desktop/fantasy_bball_slack_integration/components/daily_update', '/Users/cschafer/Desktop/fantasy_bball_slack_integration/components/daily_update']
2021-01-03 18:50:45,775 | Loading workflow module 'aws_lambda_builders.workflows'
2021-01-03 18:50:45,779 | Registering workflow 'PythonPipBuilder' with capability 'Capability(language='python', dependency_manager='pip', application_framework=None)'
2021-01-03 18:50:45,780 | Registering workflow 'NodejsNpmBuilder' with capability 'Capability(language='nodejs', dependency_manager='npm', application_framework=None)'
2021-01-03 18:50:45,782 | Registering workflow 'RubyBundlerBuilder' with capability 'Capability(language='ruby', dependency_manager='bundler', application_framework=None)'
2021-01-03 18:50:45,783 | Registering workflow 'GoDepBuilder' with capability 'Capability(language='go', dependency_manager='dep', application_framework=None)'
2021-01-03 18:50:45,784 | Registering workflow 'GoModulesBuilder' with capability 'Capability(language='go', dependency_manager='modules', application_framework=None)'
2021-01-03 18:50:45,787 | Registering workflow 'JavaGradleWorkflow' with capability 'Capability(language='java', dependency_manager='gradle', application_framework=None)'
2021-01-03 18:50:45,790 | Registering workflow 'JavaMavenWorkflow' with capability 'Capability(language='java', dependency_manager='maven', application_framework=None)'
2021-01-03 18:50:45,792 | Registering workflow 'DotnetCliPackageBuilder' with capability 'Capability(language='dotnet', dependency_manager='cli-package', application_framework=None)'
2021-01-03 18:50:45,794 | Registering workflow 'CustomMakeBuilder' with capability 'Capability(language='provided', dependency_manager=None, application_framework=None)'
2021-01-03 18:50:45,794 | Found workflow 'JavaGradleWorkflow' to support capabilities 'Capability(language='java', dependency_manager='gradle', application_framework=None)'
2021-01-03 18:50:46,549 | Running workflow 'JavaGradleWorkflow'
2021-01-03 18:50:46,550 | Running JavaGradleWorkflow:GradleBuild
2021-01-03 18:50:56,643 | JavaGradleWorkflow:GradleBuild failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.15.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aws_lambda_builders/workflows/java_gradle/actions.py", line 47, in _build_project
    self.subprocess_gradle.build(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.15.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aws_lambda_builders/workflows/java_gradle/gradle.py", line 45, in build
    raise GradleExecutionError(message=stderr.decode("utf8").strip())
aws_lambda_builders.workflows.java_gradle.gradle.GradleExecutionError: Gradle Failed: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':jar'.
> Cannot expand ZIP '/var/folders/90/ytzb7jbs72q6x6_zklk09tlm0000gr/T/tmpa7zgkyzw/7c0bdfb5795645b1a06a4b13758f35c5eca150e7/build/libs/commons.jar' as it does not exist.
```

It seems that SAM copies source code to specific temporary location in the file system, but doesn't seem to know about the subproject dependency. Does anyone have advice/suggestions on how to accommodate this code structure with AWS SAM? FWIW everything was working via AWS SAM prior to pulling shared code into it's own Gradle module.